# Unity WaitForSeconds in While Loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a system that overheat increases every 1 second. But it doesn't work, I tried so many things but code still doesn't work. Why this code is not working?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OverheatScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float overheat = 30;
    public GameObject message;

    void Start()
    {
      StartCoroutine(OverheatSystem());
    }

    IEnumerator OverheatSystem()
    {
      while (overheat < 100) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        overheat += 1;
        if (overheat >= 60) {
          message.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (overheat < 60) {
          message.SetActive(false);
        }
        Debug.Log(overheat.ToString());
      }
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you seeing in the Debug.Log() statement? The code seems syntactically correct. An alternative would be to have a counter run on the FixedUpdate() event, instead of using Coroutines.

Comment: @tutiplain is right. Also, have you make sure that you script is attached to a gameobject? Have you make sure that message is not empty and that you gave him something in the inspector?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` exactly mean? This script is attached to an object in your scene right?

Comment: Yeah it is attached to an object and it is not outputting anything.

Comment: Can you show us the inspector?

Comment: I would suggest moving the Debug.Log() to before the yield statement, just to make sure the script is running at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just stupid, I added script to object that is not active. That is why it is not working. I moved it to another object it works now.